# Azure Blob Upload File Directly to Azure from File Server

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

So right now I have a requirement to upload files directly to Azure Blob from a file server instead of using a stream in a background job. Is there anyway to upload directly to azure from a remote location given a url? Everything I see in the SDK requires the use of some form of a stream. I want to remove the service application as the middleman and let azure upload the file automatically. I couldn't find anyway to do this, nor a stack overflow answer.

Alternative Solutions
Using powershell to upload directly to azure blob. Having a specific directory act as like a queue, and any files placed there will be uploaded to azure blob from the file server. Then the background job will do what it needs to from there...

Comment: AZCopy does it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy so there has to be a way.

Comment: Is the URL of the file publicly available?

Comment: It is a Url that is only routable from within our network but azure has access through VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Andy` mentioned in the comments, you can use `azcopy` to accomplish it.

You can refer to this official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy

The grammatical form is like this：

```
azcopy cp [source] [destination] [flags]
```

---

**Update:**

I am using the [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs) SDK.

```
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
            var sourceUri = new Uri("<your-uri>");
            blobClient.StartCopyFromUri(sourceUri);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without CLI? Would the Copy methods within the .Net SDK work?

Comment: @Grim. You can use [StartCopyFromUri method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.startcopyfromuri?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_StartCopyFromUri_System_Uri_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobCopyFromUriOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

Comment: I randomly found a picture from the Internet, and it was uploaded to the storage perfectly.